# jQuery Div Toggle Issue

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Live site- http://www.arif-khan.net/other/toggle.html

Red bar on the left side is a switch to toggle a div. My problem is when you click it for first time it doesn't work, subsequent clicks it behaves as expected. I'm pretty sure that is because first time it hide div then show div. I need to fix that, so on first click it show corresponding div instead of hide it.

Code-

```
<script>
var speed = 300;
        $('#close-bar').on('click', function(){                
            var $$ = $(this);

            if( $$.is('.hide-bar') ){
                $('#toggleBox').animate({left:-212}, speed);
                $$.removeClass('hide-bar')
            } else {
                $('#toggleBox').animate({left:0}, speed);
                $$.addClass('hide-bar')
            }

        });
</script>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
var speed = 300;
$('#close-bar').on('click', function () {
    if ($(this).hasClass('hide-bar')) {
        $('#toggleBox').animate({left:0}, speed);        
        $(this).removeClass('hide-bar');
    } else {
        $('#toggleBox').animate({left:-212}, speed);
        $(this).addClass('hide-bar');
    }
});
```

## [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/RsEnH/)

Comment: Works great. Good job.

Answer (score 0):

Could try removing the is portion and replacing with hasClass (http://api.jquery.com/hasclass/)

```
if($$.hasClass('hide-bar')){

}else{

}
```

Comment: Try wrapping it in a $(function(){  });